# Execute Typescript code inside Serverless config

Tags: typescript, serverless-framework, serverless-webpack-plugin

I use [Serverless framework](https://serverless.com/framework) to deploy my backend.
My lambdas are written in Typescript and I deploy them using [serverless-webpack](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack) plugin.
Serverless allows to [reference variables in javascript files](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#reference-variables-in-javascript-files) using syntax:

```
# serverless.yml
service: new-service
provider: aws

custom: ${file(../config.js)}
```

But it works for javascript. How can I do the same with Typescript code?
My goal is to have all project code written in Typescript.

Comment: It's not about server nor lambda code. I want to have some parts of config to be generated using typescript, same as it can be done with JS (please, see the example I posted)

Comment: You can try making a JavaScript file that calls `require('ts-node').register();` and then loads your TypeScript file and copies the TypeScript file's exports to its own exports.  I wonder if loading ts-node into the Serverless CLI process will break anything.